# Display a list by display:table tag in Spring + Hibernate MVC project

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am doing on a MVC project using netbean IDE and I have a problem with displaying my objects on table
This is my jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="model.Clothes"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="cfg.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Clothes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left: 10%; ">

        <%
            Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            List<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<Clothes>();
            session1.beginTransaction();
            clothes = session1.createQuery("from Clothes").list();
            session1.getTransaction();
            System.out.println(clothes.size() + "aaaaaaaaa");
            session1.close();
            request.setAttribute("results", clothes);
        %>
        <display:table name="results" pagesize="10"/>
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="/index.htm" flush="true"/>
</body>
```

And the browser display an exception at line contains 'display' tag like this:"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/clothes.jsp" Where did I do wrong, please help me, I am newbie in java web.

p/s: I add libs in my project, they are: displaytag-1.2, displaytag-export-poi-1.2, displaytag-portlet-1.2 and commons-lang-2.6.

Comment: The rest of the error message, containing the exception message and stack trace, tells you where you did go wrong. Red it. And post it if you can't understand it.

Comment: It returns
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/NestedNullException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ; org/apache/commons/beanutils/NestedNullException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ; org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException

Comment: You're missing dependencies. Read http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/dependencies.html, or use Maven or gradle to resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: You need commit a transaction and you don't need it `session1.getTransaction();`

Comment: Check my answer below for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I followed @JB Nizet instruction and it worked, just use the libs exactly the same that listed in this link: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/dependencies.html
However, in some PC, when using org.slf4j, your project can not work properly, just remove them from the project, it is OK!